# Understanding the Unix file system and ruby installs without Sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, unix

I'm trying to comprehend the Unix file system on my OSX. I'm following wikipedia [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

I understand when I install ruby gems I must use the command `sudo gem install` but if I omit sudo, problems may occur.

1. Where are gems installed within the file system when I omit sudo?
2. How can I delete these gems?
3. A Fun side question: When I enter `cd ~/.gem` my terminal is directed to `.gem user$`, When I enter cd ~/ and list folders using the ls command I can't find a .gem folder. Where is the .gem folder? How does this fit into the Filesystem?

Comment: Use `ls -a` to see hidden folders. Folders starting with `.` are hidden by default.

Comment: Shouldn't this really be at superuser.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking over the Ruby Gems documentation http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3

the default install directory is:
`/usr/local/lib/ruby`

Ruby gems uses the environment variable `GEM_HOME` for the install path.  You can change this via the export command like so:

`$ export GEM_HOME=/home/mygemrepository $ ruby setup.rb —prefix=/home/mystuff`

You can uninstall gems with the gem uninstall command:
`gem uninstall gemtouninstall`

Finally, as I already mentioned files/folders starting with `.` (such as `.bashrc`) are hidden from `ls` by default, so use the `ls -a` option to see them. You can read more here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls

Answer (score 0):

Also, `sudo` is basically saying, "Do this action as if I was the root user," where the root user is essentially like the highest level administrator. It's a common thing to do when installing software via the command line.